# Bootstrap v4.0 form not aligning like Bootstrap v3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My form looked like this in bootstrap v3 which is what I am looking for.
[image]
*You can click on the image for enlarged view.*

When I try to use bootstrap v4 my form looks like this using the same code.
[image]

Below is my code.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="step1" style="display:block">
              <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-xs-6"> 
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What do I need to add for my form to be aligned like bootstrap v3?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try removing the `style="display:block"` on the step1 div.

Comment: @Guilherme Thanks, but that does not affect anything.

Comment: Try changing both `col-xs-6` to `col-6`

Comment: This is how it looks when I use col-6 https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/92yWm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container">    
    <div id="step1" style="display:block;" >
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-6">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-6"> 
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```